# Filter on Cell Value Inside a Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table from A2 to A7. The cell A1 doesn't belong to that table.

As long as the Cell A1 is empty the below macro works properly, but when I enter any value in cell A1 the macro stops working. The VBA debugger says: The AutoFilter Method of the Rang cannot be run (ErrorCode 1004).

```
Public Sub FilterOnCellValue()
    Dim nField As Long
    With ActiveCell
        nField = .Column - .CurrentRegion.Cells(1).Column + 1
        .CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=nField, Criteria1:=.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**The Question: How can I limit my macro to filter only inside the table?**

[image] [image]

**Update:**
I want to use this macro in all tables and all files and not in a certain table. Is there any solution?

Comment: `CurrentRegion` includes any adiacent cells and A1 is not excepted. Not making part of your table, Excel does not know what region to filter, which header to be used. But, why don't you simple use the table itself. Something like: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter Field:=.Column, Criteria1:=.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues`. It will work if you have only one table on the active sheet. Otherwise, instead of `1` (first table) you must use the table real name.

Comment: I tried the macro as explained, and it works fine with value in A1. Excel2016

Comment: @ RustyBucketBay: Do you have a table on the active sheet, starting from the second row?

Comment: @ Everyone: I want to use this macro in all tables and all files and not in a certain table. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

just pick th one your heart prefers

1. Give a name to your table and use the table.range.filter, instead of CurrentRegion.
   `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("mytable").Range.AutoFilter`
2. insert a blank and hidden row between A1 and your table

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to use this macro in all tables and all files and not in a certain table. Furthermore, it is not always possible to insert an empty row on the top of the range, otherwise, the current code (with CurrentRegion) works properly.